# Approach for detecting centroids and orientation of objects in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, feature-detection

I am trying to detect the objects in the following image and calculate the centroids and orientation of each object in the image.

My approach so far has been to remove the background from the image and isolate the objects. However, the segmentation is not precise.

What other approaches can I take? Will SURF detection, using reference images, be a more accurate approach?

My attempt:

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
figure, imshow(I)

background = imopen(I,strel('disk',15));

I2 = I - background;
figure, imshow(I2);

I3 = imadjust(rgb2gray(I2));
figure, imshow(I3);

level = graythresh(I3);
bw = im2bw(I3,level);
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 50);
figure, imshow(bw)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks pretty good to me. I think it would be good if you added another, separate image where you outline e.g. in red exactly what result you are expecting. Others can then compare their results to the ones you are expecting...

Comment: well the issue is I'm not able to get a clear segmentation of the objects to extract the centroid and orientation for each. Apologies if that wasn't clear in the question

Comment: Yes, but the segmentation is clear to me. That looks good enough for me. That is why I recommend that you add another image where you e.g. draw the segmentation area/outline you are looking for by hand. It's quite difficult for an outsider to know what "good enough" means to you.

Answer (score 1):

Nice start.

I would do the following:

1- pre process your image
apply some filters and some convolutions to remove noise; dilation and erosion for instance.

2- after calculating the thresholds, try to fill in the masks so that you closed "objects". I think imfill - http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html - will help you doing this.

Also take a look at - http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html -